# C# losing value between two controller ActionResults

Tags: c#, arrays, model-view-controller

I'm having an issue where a value seems to be being dropped between two controller ActionResults.  I'm creating request as a new ValuationRequest and adding 4 values as below.

The WriteLine correctly shows ValuationType as "lettings"

```
        request = new ValuationRequest
        {
            ValuationType = new SearchType[] { SearchType.lettings },
            Postcode = model.Postcode,
            FromDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24),
            ToDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14)
        };

        Debug.WriteLine("ValTypeBefore:" + request.ValuationType[0].ToString());
        return RedirectToAction("select-appointment", request);
```

However, when I pass request through to the next ActionResult shown below, and immediately try to Debug.WriteLine again, it errors as this value is null. The other 3 fields are being carried across perfectly.

```
        [ActionName("select-appointment")]
        public ActionResult SelectAppoinment(ValuationRequest request, ValuationModel model)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ValTypeAfter:" + request.ValuationType[0].ToString());

            var valuationAppointments = WebServiceUtility.GetValuationAppointments(request);
```

Any ideas why this would happen?

The 'request' is being passed through, but just ValuationType is being dropped.

Code for ValuationRequest class below:

```
public partial class ValuationRequest {

    private string postcodeField;

    private string officeCodeField;

    private System.DateTime fromDateField;

    private System.DateTime toDateField;

    private int durationField;

    private bool durationFieldSpecified;

    private int interludeField;

    private bool interludeFieldSpecified;

    private SearchType[] valuationTypeField;
```

Cheers

Comment: Can you show the code for class ValidationRequest?

Comment: Yep, added now.

Comment: That's  not the full class. I'm interested in the properties.

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with JSON Serialization, which only serializes public Properties.

If you redirect, your request will get serialized and then desiralized auto-magically using (usually) JSON. So you will need public Properties with getter and setter for all data you want to transmit. Also an empty Constructor.

But if those Actions are in the same controller, why don't you just call the Action Method, like any other method in c#?
So instead of

```
return RedirectToAction("select-appointment", request);
```

You write

```
return SelectAppoinment(request, model);
```

I know, not exactly what you asked for, but at least it might be a workaround.